# Do temporary residents have to pay capital gains tax on unrealized gains when they leave Canada?

Tags: stocks, canada, capital-gains-tax

Suppose I am a temporary resident in Canada for work or study. I owned some stocks before going to Canada, and bought some more during my stay in Canada. I do not sell any shares during my stay in Canada. I leave Canada after a few years. If there are unrealized capital gains when I leave Canada, do I have to pay capital gains tax on the unrealized gains?

Comment: Define 'temporary resident'. Immigration residency <> tax 'residency' status. Also, what is the other country?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Definition: [Temporary residents](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents.html). Assume that the temporary resident is resident in Canada on every day of each year. Assume that the other country has no tax-related treaties with Canada, and has no capital gains tax.

Comment: As a hypothetical, see details here: https://www.cpacanada.ca/en/news/canada/2021-05-31-departure-tax For a real-life scenario, actual facts will narrow down the answer, which has some grey areas / nuance depending on exact fact pattern.